# has changed since vs. has married since

Tags: present-perfect

In the following sentence, the present perfect "has changed since" does not sound right:

> A shocking event happened on my 18th birthday, and my life **has changed since**.

In contrast, the present perfect "has married since" sounds okay in the following:

> But I shall see them in London, as they will be there for the season. And so Ivy **has married since** her old lover, Leslie Noble, died.

Does anyone know why the present perfect is okay in one example but not in the other?

Comment: The first sentence is really not very English sounding. You are very unlikely to hear it. You would hear: X had an accident on etc.

Comment: If that's the case, replace "accident" with "event." That's not the main issue of the question.

Comment: x has changed since THEN.

Comment: What Lambie said. The only significant difference in "idiomacy" between your examples is that the first one doesn't explicitly refer to the relevant earlier time frame after the word ***since***  *(since **I turned 18**, since **Leslie died**, since **then***).

Comment: Would the first example be okay if "then" were added?

Comment: Why are you asking that again when two people have told you to add then?? **He went off to sea and hasn't been seen since**. Why don't you tell us why then is not needed there.

Comment: I am seeking confirmation.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you could tell me why it's not needed in your example. I'd love to know why.